# How to remove a 2-tuple of int/float from a list in a loop?

Tags: python, list, int, tuples, typeerror

So if I were to have a list:

```
x = [(1,3.),(2,4.),(5,6), (6,6.)]
```

how would I be able to remove the ones that have 6 as it's second(or first if in indexing terms) term? It would look like:

```
x = [(1,3.),(2,4.)]
```

The code I have tried always gave me the Errors:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

or

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
x = [item for item in x if item[1] != 6]
```